# How can I get $a(b-c) = 0$ from $ab = ac$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

[image]
[image]

How did the author comes up with the statement of $a(b-c) = 0$ from $ab = ac$?

Comment: In what context do you consider for $a,b,c$? You put a `modular-arithmetic' tag. Do you suggest that you are not talking about real numbers?

Comment: @Jack - that tag's got to be wrong, updated.

Comment: @Joffan: I'm not sure about that. Maybe OP is asking about multiplication in ${\bf Z}/n{\bf Z}$.

Comment: If $ab = ac$, then $ab-ac= 0,$ (by subtracting ac on each side of $ab=ac$). By factoring out a, from $ab-ac= 0$  we get $a(b-c) = 0$.

Comment: @youcanlearnanything: You can take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#Definition

Comment: @amWhy, thank you I understand the rationale behind the author's intention to include a(b-c) = 0 now. I dont understand why I am getting all the down votes.

Comment: Although https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/zero-product-property.html doesnt really state a(b-c)=0 as a rule.

Comment: @youcanlearnanything Which book is this ?

Comment: @A---B it is from https://brilliant.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that the setting is some [integral domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain).

First of all, author did not get from $ab = bc$ to $a(b-c) = 0$, but from $ab = ac$ to $a(b-c) = 0$.

**Step 1.** $ab = ac \implies ab - ac = 0$

Any ring is abelian group, so element $ac$ has its additive inverse denote by $-(ac) = - ac$. Since $\cdot + r\colon R\to R$ is a function for any $r$ in ring $R$, we have that for any $r\in R$ $$ab + r = ac + r.$$
In particular, letting $r = -ac$, we get $$ab+(-ac) = ac+(-ac)$$
and because $-ac$ is additive inverse of $ac$, and $-$ as operation is defined as addition by additive inverse, we get

$$ab-ac = 0$$

**Step 2.** $ab-ac = 0\implies a(b-c)= 0$

This is just distributivity. Well, not quite. Distributivity law is for addition, not subtraction, so let me prove it quickly.

The first step is to show that $-ac = a(-c)$. This is because $$ac + a(-c) = a(c+(-c)) = a\cdot 0 = 0$$ in which the first and last equality is from distributivity, while the second is property of additive inverse. Similarly, $a(-c) + ac = 0$. By uniqueness of additive inverse we get $-ac = a(-c)$.

Now,

$$ab - ac = ab + (-ac) = ab + a(-c) = a(b+(-c)) = a(b-c).$$

Comment: thank you for your clear explanation!